# Jupyter notebook, working with data for machine learning

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty new to working with jupyter notebook. I overall like it, although I sometimes get some weird errors that sometimes appear and then sometimes do not. For example, I have a data set that looks like this (showing the .head()):

[image]

Now, if I set say volume = data["avg_volume"], and then say volume.head() I get this:

[image]

But lets say I delete that line and put it somewhere else, I sometimes will get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9c1c4c11ebf0> in <module>()
----> 1 volume = data["avg_volume"]
      2 volume.head()

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I noticed that doing this after this line:

```
pnl = data["MTM_pnl"]
for data in pnl:
    if(data > 0):
        profit = np.sum(data)
print(profit)
```

will cause the problem. I just don't understand why it does this, it does not make sense to me and leads me to believe using jupyter notebook is garbage.
Here is the code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


# import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf


# In[2]:


# import dataset
data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
data.head()


# In[3]:


# Goal with data set: The goal is to maximize the PNL column, secondary goals are to minimize MAE (Maximum Adverse Excursion)
# and maximize MFE (Maximum Favorable Excursion). Once a predictable model is established the next step is to work on adding
# alpha by optimizing the stop/take profit logic.
# Assumptions: The thesis is that an earning stock (a stock that has published an earnings report in the past 24 hours) 
# that gaps on open, continues in the direction of the gap.


# In[4]:


# Get statistical information
data.describe()


# In[5]:


# See how correlated each variable is to MTM_pnl
data.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)


# In[6]:


# create some histograms
data[data.dtypes[(data.dtypes=="float64")|(data.dtypes=="int64")]
                        .index.values].hist(figsize=[11,11])


# In[7]:


# def maximize_profit(data):
#     LIR = data["LIR"]
#     volume = data["avg_volume"]
#     earnings = data["earning_time"]
volume = data["avg_volume"]
volume.head()


# In[8]:


pnl = data["MTM_pnl"]
for data in pnl:
    if(data > 0):
        profit = np.sum(data)
print(profit)


# In[9]:


volume = data["avg_volume"]
volume.head()
```

The dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/wwolfgang11/Cracking-the-Coding-Interview). No the github repository itself is not relevant but its the first idea I had to give access to the data set.

Comment: This is more likely a user error.  What is the datatype of `volume` when you receive the error?   ie, `type(volume)`

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune sure I can re-edit it give me a second.

Comment: That's the idea.  :-)  Hard-code a minimal data frame; we shouldn't have to use overhead code and a separate file to read it in.

Comment: @Prune Is the edit I made better?

Comment: No.  This is not at all minimal.  You import packages not involved in the problem, and require an input file -- which you haven't (and shouldn't) supplied.

Comment: @Prune My apologies, what do you want then? I provided the data and the code all you have to do is copy and paste and add the data into a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `for data in pnl`, you redefined the variable `data`, so it is no longer a `DataFrame` and cannot by indexed by a colum name.

And BTW, many bugs like this can be found out when you are trying to produce a *minimal, complete, verifiable example*. You'll notice that when you remove the  `for` loop this bug is gone.